# How can I achieve a better debugging console for mobile web app development?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

How can I achieve a better debugging console for mobile web app development?

Can I pipe this output to a better console?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing now ... if you have JSON objects, you can stringify them to show their contents. You can use "typeof" to display what kind of object you have. You can also reflect to the nth level:

```
for (var member in object) {
    logger('Name: ' + member + ', Value: ' + object[member]);
}
```

or something like that. There are some JQuery reflection plugins you could try.

Comment: Also, if you are needing to debug a hybrid web app (inside a UIWebView) or ON a mobile device, then what I do is create a <div id='debug'> element, then $('#debug').append('some log code'); to there, and I can see whatever I want on the web page itself.

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't work if an object has a circular reference. I'd also like to be able to trigger javascript from the console.

Comment: Normally I debug with the Safari inspector by changing the user agent to iPhone but I'm debugging touch events right now that I can't trigger in Safari.

Comment: I know how that goes - I use a javascript logger to an absolute positioned div at the top of the page. I recently did a touch event based drag and drop thing, and that very much came in handy, since Safari handles drag events fine, while iOS Safari does not.

Answer (score 0):

i found this: http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a look at both WebKit Remote Inspector and Weinre. Since both methods works in a similar way, I find WebKit Remote Inspector more handy while Weinre has a wider platform support.

[This article](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/17/enabling-remote-debugging-via-private-apis-in-mobile-safari/) explains how to activate WebKit Remote Inspector. And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759911/start-mobile-browsers-with-webkit-remote-debugging-on) seems related too.